# What all things can you do with JMX in Mule 4?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

JMX can be used to manage any Java Application in running state. Is there any restrictions of using JMX with Mule 4.x.x runtimes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as any Java application. Mule 4 by itself doesn't provide any specific JMX functionality.